# code from discord bot not running inputted code or sending error message

Tags: shell, discord, discord.py, bots

when i run this code if i submit an error it should say so but it says the code was successful even when it wasnt and when i try to open a program by saying *!runcode python main.py* it does nothing even when other commands like *!runcode start https://youtube.com/* do work

```
import discord
import asyncio
import subprocess

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online and connected to Discord!')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='with code'))
    # Send test message
    test_channel = client.get_channel(DISCORD CHANNEL ID HERE)
    await test_channel.send('Bot is working and ready to execute code.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!runcode'):
        # Get the code to run
        code = message.content[8:]
        try:
            output = subprocess.run(code, shell=True, capture_output=True)
            output_str = output.stdout.decode()
            await message.channel.send(f'Code executed successfully.\nOutput: {output_str}')
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(f'An error occurred while executing the code.\nError: {e}')

client.run('DISCORD BOT TOKEN HERE')
```

i tried to run several shell commands but im not sure what the problem is